# How to order two DatetimeOffset properties using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetimeoffset

I have class called DocumentHistory that has two `DateTimeOffset?` properties - `CreatedOn` and `ModifiedOn`. I want to be able to *order* by the *most recent time* without have to specify want property to look at first.

I have tried to order them by using Linq's `OrderByDescending`.

```
  var documentHistories = docHistory
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedOn)
    .ThenByDescending(c => c.ModifiedOn)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try implementing IComparable on your DocumentHistory class. For example, you could have something like this:

```
class DocumentHistory : IComparable<DocumentHistory>
{
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(DocumentHistory other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return 0;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return 1;

        var thisMostRecentDate = Nullable.Compare(CreatedOn, ModifiedOn) > 0 ? CreatedOn : ModifiedOn;
        var otherMostRecentDate = Nullable.Compare(other.CreatedOn, other.ModifiedOn) > 0 ? other.CreatedOn : other.ModifiedOn;

        return Nullable.Compare(otherMostRecentDate, thisMostRecentDate);
    }
}
```

Then if you just call `Sort()` on your List, it will sort them in the order you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

In general case, you can try combining all properties to choose from into a *collection* (say, array) and adding `Max()`

```
var documentHistories = docHistory
  .OrderByDescending(c => new DateTimeOffset?[] {
     c.CreatedOn,  //TODO: put all the relevant properties here 
     c.ModifiedOn,
   }.Max())
  .ToList();
```

If you have `2` properties only, you can simplify the query into

```
var documentHistories = docHistory
  .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedOn > c.ModifiedOn ? c.CreatedOn : c.ModifiedOn)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: I have other properties in the DocumentHistory class which are not datetimeoffset so i cant create a new object using DateTimeOffset

Comment: @user10609979: Which types do you have? if `DateTime` you can turn them into `DateTimeOffset`

Comment: i have string and integer properties in the class

Comment: @user10609979: if you have *different types*, e.g. `Name` and `IsDeleted` you have to *specify the order*, `{Name: "A", IsDeleted: true} < {Name: "B", IsDeleted: false}` if we start from `Name` and `{Name: "A", IsDeleted: true} > {Name: "B", IsDeleted: false}` if we start from `IsDeleted`